# Встроить в сборку pdb файл отладки

Tags: c#, отладка

Я не думаю что сложно, моя цель сделать этот файл "портативным", или что-то в этом смысле, можно ли как то его встроить в выходной исполняемый файл сборки? Не так что бы он генерировался рядом с файлом, а был именно в сборке, такое возможно?

Я так же пробовал сделать простой вариант с добавлением файла отладки в ресурсы, а потом его создать с помощью `File.WriteAllBytes("Project.pdb", Properties.Project.DebugFile);`  , но по какой то причине, когда происходит исключение идет не вся информация исключения.

Comment: По тому что pdb проверяется на наличие и подгружается при загрузке dll, а вы создаёте его позже. Вообще это лишнее, пихать его в сборку, он там лишний. На худой конец, напишите инсталлятор и разворачивайте dll и pdb из него, если хотите одним файлом.

Comment: Спасибо, я не знал что pdb подгружается на либах, буду знать. Инсталлятор это хорошо, но в мой случай не сильно влезает. Но, я рассмотрю вариант с инсталлятором. Спасибо.

Comment: Winrar exe формат подойдёт :)

Comment: Хорошо спасибо)) @NewView